# Azure WebApp recycling with BinDirChangeOrDirectoryRename shutdown reason

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-web-app-service

I have configured my Azure WebApp to be always ON via application settings, however, I found out that my application goes off without no particular reason.

So I am logging shutdown reason for every Application_End via HostingEnvironment.ShutdownReason and I am getting BinDirChangeOrDirectoryRename.

I am unable to  figure out what is the reason moreover what can I do to avoid shutting my application down.

Thank you

Comment: i would suggest you refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615193/azure-websites-appdomain-many-restarts incase if you haven't checked earlier and see if that helps.

Comment: I went through the topic and I tried to add fcnMode="Disabled" to web.confi, however, it did not help